# Find changeset using commit message mercurial

Tags: mercurial, commit, changeset

I was wondering if I can find, in mercurial, a changeset using a part of a commit message

for example I have some commits with following messages: 
"Test-254 modified some files" 
"Test-256 added logs"

And I want to find the changeset which has a commit containing Test-254 or Test-256

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mercurial supports advanced selection language called `revset`. You can access the help with `hg help revset`.

It supports both predicates and operators.

Predicates are for example `all()` to match all revision or `desc(string)` to match revisions containing string in their message.

Operators are `x:y` for selecting a range or `or` for an or condition.

By combining both, you can select the right commits you want:

- `hg log -r "desc('Test-254')"` will matches all revision that includes `Test-254` in their message.
- `hg log -r "desc('Test-256')"` will matches all revision that includes `Test-256` in their message.
- `hg log -r "desc('Test-254') or desc('Test-256')"` will matches all revision that includes either `Test-254` or `Test-256` in their message.